# Why the double.Parse throw error in live server and how to track?

Tags: asp.net, parsing

I build a website, that:

- reads data from a website by HttpWebRequest
- Sort all Data
- Parse values of the data
- and give out newly

On local server it works perfect, but when I push it to my live server, the double.Parse fails with an error.

So:
 - how to track what the double.parse is trying to parse?
 - how to debug live server?

Lang is ASP.Net / C#.net 2.0

Comment: Please show us your code and the string you're trying to parse, and tell us the locale of your machine and of the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have culture issues.

Pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to `double.Parse` and see if it helps.

To see the exception on the server, add `<customErrors mode="Off" />` to the `<system.web>` element in web.config.  (And make sure to remove it afterwords)
Alternatively, you can setup a real error logging system, such as [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/), or check the server's event log.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a problem with regional settings and the decimal separator. Might be different in your development/live servers.

Answer (score 2):

I would use **TryParse** instead of just plain **Parse**. That way, you would control what is being intended to parse.

Like this.

```
double outval;

if (!double.TryParse(yourvar, out outval)) {
  // throw and manage error on your website
}

// life goes on.
```

Comment: How come? He can log the information being parsed and act accordingly. Am I missing something else here?